# Binding jQuery .on event to dynamic button with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have a situation where I need to bind an `onclick` event to a button which is being dynamically injected into the main html document by an external JavaScript.

The problem is that that the class id of the button is suffixed with some dynamic numbers which change every time the page is reloaded.

Please see example:

```
<button class="clickme12345" type=submit value=clickme>send</button>
```

Now the situation is that on every page reload the numbers for the class id for the button will change so next time it will be `clickme67890`.

Would there be any way to get the jQuery binding to work for this situation?

Any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please include relevant code or replicate the said sample in snippet

Comment: it's really not that complicated of a code, it's something like:<button class="clickme12345" type=submit value=clickme>send</button>  , so the situation is that on every page reload the numbers for the class id for the button will change so next time it will be clickme67890.

Comment: bind the event to the parent element and let it bubble, use a css selector to specify the target of the event.  $('parent').on('click', 'button_css_selector', handler);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, in my example the class id is not static but it also changes.  Please see example in previous comments.

Comment: Dayan Moreno Leon, I don't really understand your explanation. can yo please elaborate.  Just wanted to confirm also that the class id of the button is not static and changes every single time.

Comment: @bobdabelina please include the code which your changing the `class` on page load

Comment: @jlocker, it's an external java script.  It's not my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really how you want to use it, you could use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Something like `[attr*=value]` where the `attr` contains the string `value`.

For example (in jQuery):

```
var $btnElement = $('[class*="clickme"]');
```

The above will select any elements that have a class attribute containing `clickme`